# Proving the existence of a local minimum

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

$f$ is differentiable over $\mathbb{R}$.  $f'(p) = 0, f''(p) > 0$. Prove that $f$ has a local minimum at $p$.

Proof below.  ***Can you verify or critique?***

**Notation:** If $I$ is an interval, $f(I)$ means the image of $f$ over $I$, and $f(I) < 0$ means that all $y$ in this image are $< 0$.

**Lemma 1:** If $g$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, differentiable on $(a,b)$, and $g' > 0$ on $(a,b)$, then $g(b) > g([a,b))$.  Similarly, if $g' < 0$ on $(a,b)$, then $g(b) < g([a,b))$.

**Proof:** Assume $c \in (a,b), g(c) > g(b).$  By the Mean Value Theorem, there exists $x$ in $(a,b)$ such that $g'(x) = \frac{g(c)-g(b)}{c-b} < 0$, which contradicts the hypothesis.  The proof for $g' <0$ is similar.

**Lemma 2:** If $h'(c) > 0$, then there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $h((c-\delta, c)) < h(c)$ and $h((c, c+\delta)) > h(c)$.

**Proof:** Let $0 < \epsilon < \frac{h'(c)}{2}$.  Then there exists $\delta > 0$ such that for all $x \in (c-\delta, c+\delta), |\frac{h(c) - h(x)}{c-x} - h'(c)| < \epsilon < \frac{h'(c)}{2}$, so $\frac{h(c) - h(x)}{c-x} > \frac{h'(c)}2 > 0$, so that $x < c \implies h(x) < h(c)$ and the converse $x > c \implies h(x) > h(c)$

By Lemma 2, there exists an interval around $p$ such that $x < p \implies f'(x) < 0, x > p \implies f'(x) > 0$.  By Lemma 1, $f$ therefore has a local minimum at $p$.

Please review the proof.  Is Lemma 1 required, or could the whole thing be proved via Lemma 2? Do you need the Mean Value Theorem?

Comment: Your proof is fine. Both lemmas are needed. You can't avoid mean value theorem while proving any significant result in differential calculus.